# How can I access my SanDisk sdcard from Linux Deploy

Tags: sd-card, linux

How can I access my SanDisk sdcard
I would like to know how to see it contents and set it RW property, ejected it copy,delete and so on from the command line using JuiceSSH and vnc file manager going though  Linux Deploy on android 4.2.2

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [running via Linux Deploy]
Last login: Tue Dec 15 16:16:47 2020 from localhost
$ su
root@localhost:/home/android# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:558a SanDisk Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@localhost:/home/android#
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

properties - Allow to mount the Android resources
properties - Edit the mount points list

[image] [image]

```
$ANDROID_ROOT
/cache
$ANDROID_DATA
/su
$ANDROID_STORAGE/emulated
$ANDROID_STORAGE/4D47-9860
```

this result in

```
ubuntu@localhost:~$ df -a
Filesystem                                                     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/loop1                                                 3030800  1858236    998896  66% /
proc                                                                   0        0         0    - /proc
sys                                                                    0        0         0    - /sys
tmpfs                                                            1010636      740   1009896   1% /dev
tmpfs                                                            1010636        0   1010636   0% /dev/shm
devpts                                                                 0        0         0    - /dev/pts
/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11120000.msdc0/by-name/system     2483744  2045332    422028  83% /system
/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11120000.msdc0/by-name/cache       245679     2165    226311   1% /cache
/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11120000.msdc0/by-name/userdata  11608792  8786360   2789664  76% /data
/dev/block/loop0                                                   92656     8064     82628   9% /su
/data/media                                                     11608792  8786360   2789664  76% /storage/emulated
/mnt/media_rw/4D47-9860                                         31150720 25943968   5206752  84% /storage/4D47-9860
ubuntu@localhost:~$
```

on android 4.2.2 the paths differ

```
$ANDROID_ROOT
/cache
$ANDROID_DATA
$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
$SECONDARY_STORAGE
```

this will bind mount all android partitions into linux chroot container
(the latter one is your external MicroSD card)

```
/system
/cache
/data
/storage/sdcard0
/storage/sdcard1
```

Comment: thanks but that did not work for me or you lost me in your method

Comment: have updated the paths according to some old android 4.2.2 device i found