# How to access to USB port from ubuntu emulator on android?

Tags: linux, emulators

I installed userland on my Android device and I run Ubuntu on it and connect to it with VNC server, how can I access the USB port from Ubuntu? Is it possible at all?
If userland can't access the USB port, what about other emulators like androidnix?

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: @alecxs  I can root it

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232890 you can mount usb storage as usual and add pass through mount points in settings

Comment: @alecxs where is the properties - Allow to mount the Android resources address or properties - Edit the mount points list , I Can't find it in VNC server or UserLand!